# Instance set in Java?

Tags: java, object, set, instance

Java defines a `Set` interface where [`contains()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) is defined as following:

> Returns `true` if this set contains the specified element. More
>   formally, returns true if and only if this set contains an element `e`
>   such that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`.

The `Collection` interface defines [`contains()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) as following:

> Returns `true` if this collection contains the specified element. More
>   formally, returns true if and only if this collection contains at
>   least one element `e` such that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`.

I need a Java 'instance set' where `contains()` is based on `==` and not `equals()`. In other words, a set of hard instances where two different objects A and B where `A.equals(B)` could coexist in this same set, since `A!=B`.

Is such an 'instance set' delivered in Java or in some public library? I can't find anything, but may be someone knows better on SO. If not, I'll implement it. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no direct "instance set" in the JRE.

*But* there is an [`IdentityHashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html), which implements a "instance map" according to your terminology.

*And* there is a method called [`Collections.newSetFromMap()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#newSetFromMap%28java.util.Map%29) which can create a `Set` from an arbitrary `Map` implementation.

So you can easily build your own instance set like this:

```
Set<MyType> instanceSet = Collections.newSetFromMap(new IdentityHashMap<MyType,Boolean>());
```

Comment: Looks like this is the basis I need for my instance set. Great. Thanks.

Comment: The OP should bear in mind that a `Set` implemented this way is a violation of the `Set` contract ... much as `IdentityHashMap` violates the `Map` contract.  Anyway, that's the likely reason that such a class is not a standard part of the collections framework.

Comment: @Stephen: indeed. I forgot to mention that. But *usually* when something like this is needed, it's not a big problem, because you don't try to pass that `Set` around as a "normal `Set`".

Comment: I've seen this collection used recently to fix a bug in JBoss 7, but I don't really get when you'd want to just check reference equality - can someone suggest a scenario where this would be the case?

Comment: @rich: I'm maintaining a library where custom objects (i.e. objects defined by the user) are handled on an object-identity basis (i.e. object identity matters and the user is free to implement `equals()` in any way they want, it *won't* influence what the library does with the objects). In this case I'm using `IdentityHashMap`, but I could see a use for a identity based set as well.

Comment: @rich In an app I use identity to detect changes on objects. Objects in a certain context are immutable so when a change is needed a new Object is created. A certain system detects it as new as it is not in it's previous set while the old and the new object are 'equal'.

Answer (score 1):

You could just implement the `equals` method like that:

```
public boolean equals(Obect o) {
    return this == o;
}
```

Comment: True, I could, but I would like to keep the opportunity of implementing equals() differently.

Comment: Ok :-) Just a quick heads up, I would say that almost *all* collections check reference equality before attempting to call `equals`.